# Switching Google Admob banner below Navigation toolbar

Tags: android, android-layout

In my Android App Main Activity Layout, Google Admob is placed at below Top App Bar, and i want to switch the Admob banner to below Navigation Banner.

[image]

```
<LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/container_toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="parallax">

                    <include
                        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                        layout="@layout/toolbar" />

                </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: **Welcome to stackoverflow** Share your `layout.xml` with question also read how to create [mcve]

Comment: This is my Activity_Main.xml